# How to use delay the execution of a script until something else is done?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an ASP .NET page where I use jQuery. I used this function to search an element in the DOM

$(document).ready(function() {

```
        currentID = $('#ctl00_ContentAreaPlaceHolder_hfCurrentID').val();
        if (currentID != "") {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $("div[class^='element'][ID='" +currentID + "']").trigger("click");
                $(window).scrollTop(500);
            }, 6000);
        } });
```

The problem is that when this code is executed al the DOM is not loaded, because I use an ajax call to create the grid that contains the  'element_r1c1' (r means row, and c means column) elements. Thats why I use the window.setTimeout to wait until the DOM is loaded, but this only works if the DOM is loaded in less than 6 seconds. So, I need a way to tell this function to execute after the ajax function has ended. For additional info, this code is in the page (.aspx) and the ajax function is in a control (.ascx)

Update:

I have two pages, the BasePage, the GridPage. The control is in the GridPage, and is called by the first page with

```
$('#tabs').tabs({

        select: function(event, ui) {
            // default shows All action elements
            $.ajax({
                url: 'GridPage.aspx?viewingDate=' + $(ui.tab).attr('Date'),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    //debugger;
                    $('#tabContent').empty().html(data);
                }
            });
            $('#nPaneArea').html('').removeClass().addClass('Pane');
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should delete your question and ask a new one that isn't community wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of waiting an arbitrary period of time and then executing unconditionally, check to see if you actually got anything with your jQuery selector every couple hundred milliseconds before acting.

```
function triggerClickOnReady(id) {
    return (function() {
        var $element = $("#" + id);
        if ($element.size() > 0) {
            $element.trigger("click");
            $(window).scrollTop(500);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout( triggerClickOnReady(id), 200);
        }
    });
}
```

You'll need to return a function so that you can pass in currentId and hold its value with a closure.

Then, in the `success` callback in your AJAX request...

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#tabContent').empty().html(data);
    triggerClickOnReady(currentId);
}
```

Comment: how to raise the event if I'm using $.ajax from jQuery to retrieve the grid?

Comment: Or is it possible to create a state machine in javascript?

Comment: If you're going to do it as a callback on the second example code you posted above it could be a little simpler. I'll edit my example...

Comment: Now that I think about it, you're selecting an element with a particular class, and then checking if it has a particular Id. Id's are unique, so all you need to do is check the Id. That will be a much faster selector. Editing again...

Comment: This is assuming `currentId` is available in the scope where this is called. I'm assuming it isn't known until runtime as you have it in your example.

Comment: Perfect, I'm going to implement it in my project

Answer (score 4):

So you need to execute this script in the success callback of the AJAX script that is loading the grid. As you've tagged this with ASP.NET I guess you are using UpdatePanel to trigger AJAX calls. If this is the case you could use the [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) event:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {
    // do the jQuery stuff here
});
```

Comment: The call is made with jQuery $.ajax

Comment: @firematta, well then it's even easier: simply use the `success` callback provided by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you're trying to execute a function after the DOM loads and you get a reply to an AJAX request.

You can set a flag in each completion handler for these two events, and, in each one, check whether the other flag is set, and, if it is, execute your function.

Comment: could you explain me with code? Because I'm more like a backend guy, and I really got messy when I go to client side